# font-face does not display on Mac

Tags: css, macos, font-face

I have a very strange problem in a website.

We've recently launched a [**website**](http://www.makeyourday.gr), which works fine on PC. But when it comes to Mac the browser does not display any fonts at all.

I am using `font-face` to include a specific font and there are 2 different stylesheets, depending on screen width. I have tried several options found here but none seemed to work. The last syntax i used in my css was like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'ChollaSansGr';
    src: url('http://:/')format('IE-No-404'),url('./fonts/ChSaGrRg.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

So my question is if can anyone help me with the solution or give a suggestion about what could be the root of the problem.

Comment: Which browser are you using on the Mac?

Comment: Are you sure about this: `'http://:/'`?

Comment: I am using Safari. I wasn't sure about the http:// but i was trying things. I tried the solution reno suggested but safari seems to fail to find the proposed font files and rendering a usual one. The problem is only on MAC on all browsers, as Safari on windows works perfect... The problem must be with the paths as i see that in firefox on MAC the system also renders another font style and not ChollaSans.

Comment: EDIT: Found that the best syntax is   @font-face {
    font-family: 'ChollaSansGr-Bold';
    src: url('chsagrbd.eot');
    src: url('chsagrbd.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('chsagrbd.woff') format('woff'),
       url('chsagrbd.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('chsagrbd.svg#chsagrbd') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  } Like this it renders in Firefox OS but the problem still exists in Safari.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Safari, I found this solution on the Net:

> Well it turns out I DID solve it, at least so far on Mac. Here it is:
>
> font-squirrel and font registries that create webkits generate the CSS
>   using " and ' around the URLs. This seems to jack things up. They also
>   set all the weights and styles to normal which also seems to wreak
>   havoc.
>
> here is the code generated by font squirrel for 2 of the faces of
>   Lato:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBlackItalic';
    src: url('Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.svg#LatoBlackItalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoBlack';
    src: url('Lato-Black-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Lato-Black-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Lato-Black-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Lato-Black-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Lato-Black-webfont.svg#LatoBlack') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

> Here is what I changed it to that actually works in Safari and Chrome
>   and Firefox:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: Lato;
    src: url(../../fonts/Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.eot);
    src: url(../../fonts/Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype),
         url(../../fonts/Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.woff) format(woff),
         url(../../fonts/Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.ttf) format(truetype),
         url(../../fonts/Lato-BlackItalic-webfont.svg#LatoBlackItalic) format(svg);
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: italic;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: Lato;
    src: url(../../fonts/Lato-Black-webfont.eot);
    src: url(../../fonts/Lato-Black-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype),
         url(../../fonts/Lato-Black-webfont.woff) format(woff),
         url(../../fonts/Lato-Black-webfont.ttf) format(truetype),
         url(../../fonts/Lato-Black-webfont.svg#LatoBlack) format(svg);
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Link is here : <s>http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10797/font-face-not-working-in-only-safari-/p1</s>

Hope this helps.